# how can i use self-defined view in the res/layout/main.xml file

Tags: android, user-interface

The problem is proposed because I want to edit the position, color, and other display properties in the "what you see is what you get" mode; therefore, add some specific behavior in its onDraw(Canvas) function. So, i want to rewrite the view class, currently use own-defined class in res/layout/main.xml is unsupported.

Anyone knows some solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create your own class that extends View and override onDraw method. Than use it in xml with the fully qualified name of the class. Something like this

```
....
<your.package.MyView android:id="@+id/my_id" ..../>
....
```

Then in your code get a reference to it like this

```
MyView mv = (MyView)findViewById(R.id.my_id);
```

[Here](http://www.permadi.com/blog/2010/03/android-sdk-using-custom-view-in-xml-based-layout/) is good example of the above.

Comment: thanks for your answer, Mojo. Now i have another question, I managed to define a MyLayout class in the main activity, MovingBoxActivity, and refer it with com.ijowett.MyLayout. But if I want to define the MyLayout as the inner class of MovingBoxActivity so that I can access the private member of MovingBoxAcitvity. How to do that?

Comment: If you defined it as inner class it should be static and you can use it like this MovingBoxActivity.MyLayout. But when class is static it does not keep a reference to the parent class so you'll not be able to access it members. Simple solution of this will be when you instantiate MyLayout to have some setters to set the desired fields - MyView mv = (MyView)findViewById(R.id.my_id); mv.setNeededFiled(field_1); .... and so on;

Comment: Yes. We must do external efforts for this accessment. Seems there hasn't a good way to make it, i just want to develop between UI editor and code. This can be an improvement idea for google android.